# Laravel image uploader

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I'm trying to do a image upload on a form method but when i'm validating it always return an error saying the file is not an image. here you can see my html image uploader form:

```
<div class="row form-group">
     <h4><strong>Imagen</strong></h4>
    <input type="file" id="picture" name="picture" accept=".jpeg,.jpg,.png">
</div>
```

and my controller where i'm making my validation:

```
$this->validate(request(),[
        'nombre' => 'required|min:5',
        'precio' => 'required|numeric',
        'descripcion' => 'required|min:10',
        'alto' => 'required|numeric',
        'ancho' => 'required|numeric',
        'largo' => 'required|numeric',
        'categoria' => 'required|numeric',
        'picture' => 'image|required',
    ]);

    $store = new articulo();
    $store->nombre = request('nombre');
    $store->categoria_id = request('categoria');
    $store->precio = request('precio');
    $store->descripcion = request('descripcion');
    $store->alto = request('alto');
    $store->ancho = request('ancho');
    $store->largo = request('largo');
    $store->image = request('picture');

    $store->save();
```

Comment: use this rule for the image; 'image' => 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif|required|max:10000' // max 10000k

Comment: still not recognizing the png file

Answer (score 0):

For image validation try this:

```
'picture' => 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,png|required'
```

You can also add `max:5000` file size validation.

Hope that help

Comment: i had this error "The picture must be a file of type: jpeg, jpg, png." and it's actually a png file

Comment: Are you sure of the picture extension? That seems like it did not pass the validation rules

Comment: http://imgur.com/1TKWAZU  There's the image, and i just dd(request('image')) and it said 'tux.jpg'

Answer (score 0):

To upload an image your form must have the attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"` so it submits the image as a file and not a string. Your form should be similar to this:

```
<form action="/yourroute" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
....
    <div class="row form-group">
        <h4><strong>Imagen</strong></h4>
        <input type="file" id="picture" name="picture" accept=".jpeg,.jpg,.png">     
    </div>
....
</form>
```